# Split 8 bit byte

Tags: c#, arrays, byte

So Say I have an array of bytes that is 16 long, with each 8 bits representing my data and an array that is 8 long with each 4 bits (so 2 per byte) representing my data.

If I wanted to loop over these and get the values, what would be the easiest way of doing so?

My poor attempt would be something like this, but this doesn't appear to be working as I expect.

```
for(int i = 0; i < bigByteArray.Length; i++) 
{
    byte BigByteInfo = bigByteArray[i];
    byte SmallByteInfo;
    if(i % 2 == 0)
    {
        SmallByteInfo = smallByteArray[i / 2] % 16;
    }
    else
    {
        SmallByteInfo = smallByteArray[i / 2] / 16;
    }

    //Use of data Here.
}
```

Comment: how does it not to appear to work? It actually looks good

Comment: What do you expect, and what does happen?

Comment: Perhaps I messed something else up. Hmm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this class as helper class

```
public class FoutBitsArrayEnumerator : IEnumeable<byte>
{
  FoutBitsArrayEnumerator(byte[] array)
  {
    this.array = array;
  }
  public IEnumerator<byte> GetEnumerator
  {
    foreach (byte i in array)
    {
        yield return i & 15;
        yield return (i >> 4) & 15;
    }
  }

  byte[] array;
}
```

Comment: Won't compile for the same reason as the OP; you're missing a conversion to byte.  You also have a few typos (IEnumeable, missing method parentheses, etc.)

Comment: What i meant was to give him the direction not a compilable solution.

Comment: I actually implemented a solution like this now, it's a lot cleaner to read, thanks. Unfortunately my problem didn't lie in reading the data incorrectly, it was my idiocy in checking if the data was right :P

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right (bigByteArray is 16 long, smallByteArray is 8 long, packed):

```
for(int i = 0; i < bigByteArray.Length; i++)
{
    bigByteArray[i] = (byte)((smallByteArray[i / 2] >> (i % 2 == 0 ? 4 : 0)) & 0xF);
}
```

Comment: your onelinre doesn't do anything notably different than his code snippet which looks on first sight good as well. It looks like his expectation of what should happen is different than the actual output

Comment: @Toad, they're similar.  However, his won't compile for at least one reason (missing a conversion to byte).  The above is tested.

Comment: I hope that is the issue he is facing!   (p.s. did you consider using (i&1) instead of (i%2) for readability and perhaps even speed(on embedded systems))?

Comment: @Toad, I prefer `% 2` when I'm checking whether I'm on an even or odd iteration.  However, I don't think there's much difference here in readability or performance.

Comment: Yeah I was converting to byte in my actual program, didn't include it in my example sorry :P. As it turns out I was getting the right results, I'm just an idiot. Thanks for your attempts to help :) Hope you don't mind me accepting the other answer (as I actually implemented a class like his anyway) even though it wasn't really the answer.